# Updating a table after adding Index

Tags: database, indexing, sql-server-express, ssms

I am designing a database using SQLExpress.
I have a table which has three columns. The table looks as below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dummy](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[someLongString] [text] NOT NULL,
[someLongText_Hash] [binary](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dummy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I already have some data in this table. Whenever I want to add a new row, I first compute a hash on `someLongString` and query the table to see if a row with this hash already exists. As the table size grows, this query talks longer time and hence I plan to index it by the `someLongText_Hash` column.

Can some please suggest how to do this in SQL Server Management Studio. Also, after adding this index, how do I index the existing rows in this table ?

Comment: Why are you using `TEXT`? You should be using `VARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: @AaronBertrand, how is using Varchar(MAX) better than using Text ?

Comment: `TEXT` is deprecated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just set the 'someLongString' field to be unique? That way you don't need to keep a hash and an extra primary key?

You could try using a CHECKSUM.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dummy](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[someLongString] [text] NOT NULL,
[someLongText_CheckSum] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [UC_someLongText_CheckSum] UNIQUE (someLongText_CheckSum),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dummy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

See [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1868/sql-server-unique-constraints-for-large-text-columns/) for further explanation

Comment: `someLongString` is `TEXT`. You can't make `TEXT` unique - the maximum length for a unique key is 900 bytes.

Comment: I made the `someLongText_Hash` field as `UNIQUE` and that works. However I am querying the bale based on this field later, so I want to Index it too. But I am not able to see this option in SQL Server Management.